# Why doesn't my button work in NativeScript?

Tags: button, navigation, nativescript

This is kind of embarrassing because I feel like I should not be having this issue, but I just can't figure out why my button is not redirecting me to another page.

I was trying to make a button that navigated to another page in NativeScript.